# Issue with Athena Query to find the missing months and days in a set of timestamps

Tags: sql, aws-lambda, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have data stored in s3 in a partitioned format by month at this s3 location: s3://monitoring-v0-test-new-files-per-day/CPUUtilization/.

The data is in json format and a sample is this:

> {"AccountID":"607780019502","CPUUtilization":"0.338983","EC2Instance":"i-0765e8787747b9aff","Region":"us-east-1","TimeStamp":"2023-01-05T23:00:00Z","month":"1"} .

I have loaded the data into an athena db called test_db in athena and in a test_table.

The table columns are `CPUUtilization` string, `AccountID` string, `Region` string, `TimeStamp` string, `month` string and partitioned by months .

I need to find the missing months and days by creating an athena query based on the partition using Athena engine version 3.

So far i've been able to come up with this:

https://go.dev/play/p/P86fvWwFcX_n

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 
    CAST(date_parse(TimeStamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ') AS DATE) AS day,
    month
  FROM test_db.test_table
), 
all_months_days AS (
  SELECT 
    date_trunc('month', day) AS month, 
    DATE_ADD(date_trunc('month', MIN(day)), INTERVAL seq-1 MONTH) AS all_months
  FROM data, 
  UNNEST(SEQUENCE(DATEDIFF(date_trunc('month', MAX(day)), date_trunc('month', MIN(day))) + 1)) seq
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT 
  all_months, 
  array_agg(DISTINCT day ORDER BY day) AS all_days, 
  array_difference(array_agg(DISTINCT all_months ORDER BY all_months), array_agg(DISTINCT month ORDER BY month)) AS missing_months, 
  array_agg(DISTINCT month ORDER BY month) AS available_months
FROM all_months_days
LEFT JOIN data ON date_trunc('month', day) = all_months
GROUP BY 1
```

But I keep getting this error:

> line 10:54: mismatched input 'seq'. Expecting: ',',

Ideally I plan to run the query in golang using the athena client, I just want to be sure it works out in Athena.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested your query (if you need further help - please provide sample data and desired output), but there is at least one error - your [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) syntax is wrong - you need to provide the "synthesized" table name and column names for it, i.e. in your current query you are missing the column spec. You can change it to something like:

```sql
UNNEST(
  SEQUENCE(
    DATEDIFF(
      date_trunc('month', MAX(day)), date_trunc('month', MIN(day))) + 1)) t(seq) -- t - table name, seq - column name
```

For inserting missing timestamps also check this answers:

- [Presto - Insert Missing Timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69744008/presto-insert-missing-timestamps/69744370#69744370)
- [Rolling distinct count for last 3 days (Presto DB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73138475/rolling-distinct-count-for-last-3-days-presto-db/73139698#73139698)